# Configuring H5py with mpio using Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi, conda, h5py

I want to create an h5 file, in order to do that, in my case, the different process has to read separately file, and attach some value to a column of the common dataset.

I was thinking to do It by using, mpio and h5py through python, and the interpreter is a conda environment. 
But when I try to launch a simple program like this one: (as shown in the doc-site:http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html)

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import h5py

rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank  # The process ID (integer 0-3 for 4-process run)

f = h5py.File('parallel_test.hdf5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)

dset = f.create_dataset('test', (4,), dtype='i')
dset[rank] = rank

f.close()
```

I got Always this error:

**AttributeError: 'h5py.h5p.PropFAID' object has no attribute 'set_fapl_mpio'**

In the Anaconda environment I installed:

```
conda install h5py
conda install mpio
```

What I would like to know Is, if Is It possible to do such kind of configuration on Windows, or how this error can be solved.

Comment: Parallel HDF5 with h5py isn't an "out of the box" capability. Did you follow the steps to build against Parallel HDF5? They are described in this section: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html#building-against-parallel-hdf5

Comment: I do not know where i can access to that configuration beacuse throught Anaconda i was not able to find that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been looking for a clean way of installing h5py with MPI support using conda and the following worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge "h5py>=2.9=mpi*"
```

I found it in this GitHub discussion: https://github.com/conda-forge/h5py-feedstock/issues/44

I have not been able to specifically test it on Windows, though.